# what is the difference between "Commerce Product Attributes" and "Commerce Customizable Products"

Tags: commerce

[Commerce Product Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes)

[Commerce Customizable Products](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product)

What is the difference between these 2 modules.?

I'm creating orders from a view table, without a product display for each product. I've added a text field to a custom line item with "Commerce Customizable Products" module. The line item display shows the fields but I cant find how to edit it. (working on panels btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm bad in english, but still try to explain.

Product attributes are always set by the administrator, and customer can not change it. For example, if you set a colour as product attribute, you also have to define all possible variants of colors. There is no difference whether you are using conversion rates depending on the color value of the attribute or not.

Customizable products, however, allow the customer to select an attribute value depending on the preference. For example, if you sell T-shorts, you are able to allow customers choose an inscription on a T-shirt, without price changing. Customer may order T-short with any inscription that he wants to.

To be more precise, trying to explain the difference in terms of data structures. Product attributes add fields to commerce product entity, and customizable products add fields to line item entity. So there is the main difference with all the consequences.

Based on my experience:

I use a Customizable products to sell tea sold by weight. Customer allowed to enter any amount of tea in grams, and then i recalculate sell price using rules.

Comment: With Commerce Customizable Products I've added a text field on the line item and updated the view display to show the field. Is there a way a admin can change the value on the order page at "admin/commerce/orders/*/edit"

Comment: Line items table there is not a view, so it can not display Customizable product fields. The easiest way is to delete line item and then add them with required value. Also you can check [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1546026) or override whole table manually.

Comment: Thanks. Inline entity form seems to add this capability as mentioned in your link. https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form

Comment: i'm glad to help you :)